# Routine question about derivatives of automorphic forms being L^2

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I consider Automorphic forms on $G = SL_2 (\mathbb{R})$, which are $\Gamma$-invariant, $K$-finite, $Z(g)$ finite, and of moderate growth. If I have such an automorphic form, which happens to be in $L^2(\Gamma \backslash G)$, is it true that if we will act on it by some element of the Lie algebra, the result will also be in $L^2$?

Thank you,
Sasha

Comment: I'm confused by a few parts of this question. Is $G=SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ here, because both appear? Second, is the automorphy factor trivial, because it seems you are considering the form to be a function on $\Gamma\setminus G$ rather than on $G$.

Comment: Yes; $G$ equals $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, and the automorphy factor is trivial (Because I just try to understand this most basic setting).

Answer (score 2):

If you allow yourself to use the fact that $L^2$, $\mathfrak z$-finite $K$-finite automorphic forms are finite linear combinations of $L^2$ eigenfunctions, here cuspforms and constants, then on-the-right derivatives map such finite linear combinations to finite sums of the same type, which are again in $L^2$.

Thus, one would want to prove that no $L^2$ continuous spectrum can be $\mathfrak z$-finite and $K$-finite, which is a corollary of Plancherel.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, your answer depends on some things which are "hard" relative to where I stand. But I will keep it in mind when I'll try to understand the "Plancherel".

Answer (score 2):

There is a claim (Borel, Automorphic forms on $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, 2.14) that if $f$ is $K$-finite on the right and $Z(g)$-finite, then it can be represented as convolution of itself with a smooth function $\phi$ with compact support. Then it is quite clear that if it is in $L^2$, if we take derivative, and "throw" it into the $\phi$ place, we will get a convolution of $L^2$ with a smooth function with compact support, hence again something in $L^2$.

Comment: Yes, such an argument can get to the conclusion you want, but the context you use is considerably subtler than Plancherel, in fact. Of course it depends on where one sees it... one's prior background, ... Perhaps in the extant literature the simplicity and utility of automorphic Plancherel are under-served.